# Wordpress API Get Posts by category

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

Is it possible to get all posts by category?

http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working in the end by using the optional filters parameter. According to the documentation these are the following accepted filter parameters.

struct filter: Optional.
    string post_type
    string post_status
    int number
    int offset
    string orderby
    string order

Out of curiousity I sent over a 'category' filter by adding the following to `class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php` under the getposts method

```
if(isset($filter['category']))
     $query['category'] = absint($filter['category']);
```

before the `wp_get_recent_posts{$query);` method is called

and it worked! It seems like `Wordpress` have left out a few filter parameters from their documentation.

You can also send over a search filter by passing over 's' as the filter

```
$query['s'] = $filter['s'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is a way to filter beforehand. You may need to run the API call and filter afterwards.

You'd probably be best off asking on the [stackexchange wordpress site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: hmm that's what I feared :/ Thanks for the link to the wordpress stackexchange, I was unaware of it. I've asked the same question on there http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140799/wordpress-api-xml-rpc-get-posts-by-category

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy after all. From this [WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90173/12615), we learn that we can extend the XML-RPC methods and create our own `my.getPosts`, like show by this William P. Davis' [extension code on GitHub](https://github.com/bangordailynews/WordPress-xmlrpc-extenders) <sub><sup>[- - *fork*](https://github.com/brasofilo/WordPress-xmlrpc-extenders)</sup></sub>.

Basically, create a plugin with the following code and adapt the arguments accepted to produce the output:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'add_my_xmlrpc_methods' );

function add_my_xmlrpc_methods( $methods ) {
    $methods['bdn.getPosts'] = 'bdn_xmlrpc_get_posts';
    return $methods;
}

function bdn_xmlrpc_get_posts( $args ) {
    # Adapt wp.getPosts to your needs
    # https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php#L1553
}
```