# wp xml-rpc wp.getPost

Tags: wordpress, api, xml-rpc

I try to get all post of a particularly category into an iPhone app, I know how get all posts, but I don't know how can I pass the category id because in wp api I don't see any option for filter posts per cat.

http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPost

how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress API Get Posts by category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968236/wordpress-api-get-posts-by-category)